# How to join lines in csv if number of fields is less

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file which is broken. There are endlines within the fields (both linux and windows). I know the number of fields in each row say `N`. For e.g. for N=5

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
field6,field7,fie
ld8,field9,field10
...
```

How to join (coalesce ?) smaller lines to form a regular line with `N` fields assuming no other exceptions. I can convert the windows endings with `tr -d '\r'` but what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will group the broken lines together to get to five fields:

```
$ awk -F, 'last{$0=last $0;} NF<5{last=$0;next} {print;last="";}' file
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
field6,field7,field8,field9,field10
```

#### How it works

awk reads in a record (line) at a time and divides the line into fields.  The goal is to merge/coalesce lines as needed to assure that they have five fields.

**Summary:** Any short line is saved in the variable `last` and attached to the next line.  When a line has five or more fields, it is printed.

**Details:**

- `-F,`

  This sets the field separator to a comma.
- `last{$0=last $0;}`

  If the previous line had less than five fields, it is saved in the variable `last`.  If `last` is not empty, prepend to the beginning of the current line.
- `NF<5{last=$0;next}`

  If the current line has less than five fields, save it in `last` and jump to the `next` line.
- `{print;last="";}`

  If we got to here, then the current line has at least 5 fields.  Print it. Set `last` to the empty string.

Comment: Works but there is a bug, it keeps adding an old field to every line after replacement. So after 1 replacement  number of field is +1 for every line thereafter. The regular case N = 5 is not be handled properly I think.

Comment: I was running the code in the older version. This one runs fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat fileName | tr -d '\r' | tr -d '\n'> newFile
```

Comment: That would delete all line endings. I need N fields per row. Is there any way to make last `tr` conditional.